# Concept of boost property maps

Tags: c++, boost

I am still struggling understanding the following aspect of boost property maps:

Do boost property maps actually store data, or is the data stored in another data structure and the boost property maps are merely a way of accessing this data? In other words, is the space complexity of a property map constant no matter how much data can be access through it?

If that is the case, then why does it feature a put function?

Comment: The point is to have a common interface for both cases: a concrete map, or data stored elsewhere.

Comment: @Marc Glisse Thank you for your comment. So the size of a property map is constant? But in that case, why is there at put() function?

Comment: The property map is just an interface. It tells you how to read (get) or write (put) stuff. If you look at `http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html` in the example the property map references an std::map, which is where `put` writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space complexity is definitely not constant. Miracles are not possible. The more data you store, the more space is needed.

The best way of understanding property maps from my point of view is wrapping. You add a property - your class is wrapped with another class that `handles` this property. This wrapper class is generated dynamically during the template instantiation. I looked in the debugger at what they generate. It showed inheritance layer for each property that I defined.

Exact place of storing the data is hidden in the implementation. This is part of their design and of what they wanted to achieve. This also gives them certain flexibility in implementing the storage in this or that way.